# Measuring Euclidean Distance on pixel level with PIL / Image.Point()

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, euclidean-distance

I am using Python Image Library to get a sort of brightness value for each pixel, based on its Euclidean Distance measured from white.
From what I can discern from PIL's documentation, `Image.point()` manipulates each pixel according to a color table. But what I need is a way to reach each pixel's value in a way similar to this: `pixel.r` `pixel.g`  `pixel.b` in order to use them to fit the calculation to the distance formula.

I'm new to PIL, and its documentation is a bit fuzzy. Is `Image.point()` up to a task like this? If not, where else might I look?

Comment: You may want to check bands - I assume RGB - then getdata(). That give you a list (iterator to) and data[x] = (r, g, b).From here you can get eache level, and much faster than getpixel. Only be careful to convert coordinates in plain numbers - width/height - since this list is a linear indexed object from 0 to width x height - 1

Comment: Works nicely, thank you.